# Python random numbers multiple times

Tags: python, random, numbers

```
import random

def main():
    uinput()

def uinput():
    times = int(input('How many numbers do you want generated?'))
    number1 = int(input('Put in the first number:' ))
    number2 = int(input('Put in the second number:'))
    rnumber = random.randint(number1, number2)
    print (rnumber)



main()
```

I am messing around in Python, and I want my program to generate random numbers. As you can see I have already accomplished this. The next thing I want to do is have it generate multiple random numbers, depending on how many numbers the "user" wants generated. How would I go about doing this? I am assuming a loop would be required.

Comment: So [read about loops](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html), write a loop, and report back!

Comment: if number1>number2 you will get `ValueError`

Comment: If you know the range you want to pick from, you can also use `random.choices(range, k=n)`, where `n` is the number of numbers to yield.

Answer (score 8):

This will produce a list of random integers in range `number1` to `number2`

```
rnumber = [random.randint(number1, number2) for x in range(times)]
```

For more information, look at [List Comprehension.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a loop that simply adds to an existing string:

```
import random
from random import randint
list=""
number1=input("Put in the first number: ")
number2=input("Put in the second number: ")
total=input("Put in how many numbers generated: ")
times_run=0
while times_run<=total:
    gen1=random.randint(number1, number2)
    list=str(list)+str(gen1)+" "
    times_run+=1
print list
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a "for" loop. For example:

```
for i in xrange(times):
    # generate random number and print it
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generators and iterators:

```
import random
from itertools import islice

def genRandom(a, b): 
    while True:
        yield random.randint(a, b)


number1 = int(input('Put in the first number:' ))
number2 = int(input('Put in the second number:'))
total = int(input('Put in how many numbers generated:'))

rnumberIterator = islice(genRandom(number1, number2), total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to take user input to generate numbers in a given range. You can return the function or print the function.

```
import random

def ran_nums():
    low_range = int(input('Enter the low end of the range: '))
    high_range = int(input('Enter the high end of the range: '))
    times = int(input('How many numbers do you want to generate? '))
    for num in range(times):
        print(random.randint(low_range,high_range))
```

Answer (score -2):

This code chooses a random number:

```
import random
x = (random.randint(1, 50))
print ("The number is ", x)
```

Repeat the code 6 times to choose 6 random numbers.